# How hide the KeyBoard in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I read a lot of thing, but anyone asked me.  I am in a

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

So the user clicked in my tableView. I am not in a UITextField. All I want is say to Keyboard screen go away animated, like when it close normally. How can I do this command:

[keyboard goway];

Comment: hi, welcome on SO, first we don't use **** words here. Also you should add some language and platform tags. I add iphone tag(fix it if i was wrong with your platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dismiss the keyboard, you need to call resignFirstResponder. First though, you need figure out what object is first responder.

It's usually a textField, but it can be other things. For this example, you would call

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

What object is using the keyboard? We may be able to help you further.

Comment: Like, this is the biggest problem. I am using a UIWebView and the user click in a TextBox of the page. I intercept the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and open the UITableView. When the user click in something, it enter the text in webpage via JavaScript. So, I don't need more the Keyboard, and I don't have access in textField. I can't use the `resignFirstResponder`...

Comment: Does it work if you remove this observer? Also, have you set the VC as the UIWebView delegate?

Answer (score 0):

the UITableView should call `becomeFirstResponder`

Or, I guess a much easier way is not to rely on the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, instead, you hijack the click event of the TextBox in your html, and run `document.location = 'blablabla'; preventDefault();`, then your uiwebview delegate will knew it's time to call out the UITableView. This way is better because keyboard won't even show up.